# Replace a filename in init.el using sed from bash script

Tags: init-file, custom

So I have different customized themes.  Different customized themes are written to a separate custom `.el` files and get called in the main `init.el` file. For example:

```
(setq custom-file "~/.emacs.d/myCustomSettings/customDarkLaptop.el")
```

will call the `customDarkLaptop.el`, where all of my customized variables like font size, comment color..etc.

Suppose I want to switch to a different customized themes, I then go to `init.el` and change this

```
(setq custom-file "~/.emacs.d/myCustomSettings/customLight.el")
```

which will then load the `customLight.el`  file.

I would like to write a script to automate this process, user just need to enter either the part after `custom` to the desire theme.  For example:

- enter `Dark` will automatically have `customDark.el`

Replacing text from a file can be easily be done with the `sed` command, i.e.

```
sed -i -e s/oldtext/newtext/g <enter file name here>
```

However, I am not sure how to incorporate this efficiently into my `init.el` file.  What I want is something like this:

- create a string variable in `init.el`:  `themeName = "Dark"`
- Append it to my `set-q` command file path like this:

  `(setq custom-file "~/.emacs.d/myCustomSettings/custom<INSERT THE VARIABLE themeName HERE>.el")`

My `sed` script will just replace one thing, the variable `themeName` in `init.el`.

How do you do this in elisp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me just what you need/want, or why you're using `sed` and `bash` (what you're using them for).

Maybe what you really want is to just have loading your init file prompt you for which theme you want.  If so, you can do that by putting code in your init file similar to this:

```lisp
(setq custom-file  (format "~/.emacs.d/myCustomSettings/custom%s"
                           (read-string "Theme/style: " nil nil "Light")))
(load-file custom-file))
```

If you want to be able to (re)load a given custom file anytime you can put such code in a command.

That code assumes you want to set `custom-file` to the given value, rather than just load the file.  You would do that in order for Emacs to thereafter update the right `custom-file` if you use Customize etc.  If you don't care about that then you can just use something like this:

```lisp
(load-file (format "~/.emacs.d/myCustomSettings/custom%s"
                   (read-string "Theme/style: " nil nil "Light")))
```